# CSS Parent Class over other CSS Classes

Tags: css, class, styles, element, parent

My Code Looks something like this:

```css
input{
...
}

label{
...
}
```

```html
<div class="textfield 1">
  <input tpye="text" id="fullname">
  <label for="fullname">Name</label>
</div>

<div class="textfield 2">
  <input tpye="text" id="fullname">
  <label for="fullname">Name</label>
</div>

<div class="textfield 3">
  <input tpye="text" id="fullname">
  <label for="fullname">Name</label>
</div>
```

now i want to apply the css only on one of the textfields and because the code is way to long to ad a ".textfield1" to every css element i want to ask if i can create a "parent class element" like:

```css
.textfield1{

    input{
    ...
    }

    label{
    ...
    }
       }

.textfield2{

    input{
    ...
    }

    label{
    ...
    }
       }
```

It's like putting the styled elements in a Folder.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: CSS no. SCSS yes. But your selectors are wrong anyway. It would be `.textField.1`. Except of course that [classes can not start with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) so yours would be invalid. If you are only wanting to style one element why would you need to add a class to every element? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.textfield1 input {
    ...
}

.textfield1 label {
    ...
}
```

Check this link for more CSS selectors combinations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 0):

As Turnip mentions in comments, you cannot have spaces in classnames. So instead of having class names such as `textfield 1`, you could have them like `textfield1` - or something else. For the time being, I am using `textfield1` to demonstrate the solution.

Now, you could use the [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) `.textfield1 input` (notice the space between the class name and tag name) or the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `.textfield2 > input` (notice the arrow `>` between the class name and tag name) to specify that given CSS rule must apply only to the descendants or children of given class.

```css
input{
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

label{
  color: blue;
}

.textfield1 input {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.textfield2 > input {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="textfield1">
  <input tpye="text" id="fullname">
  <label for="fullname">Name</label>
</div>

<div class="textfield2">
  <input tpye="text" id="fullname">
  <label for="fullname">Name</label>
</div>

<div class="textfield3">
  <input tpye="text" id="fullname">
  <label for="fullname">Name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use preprocessor like Sass or Less, you can nasted css like your example. It's not possible in the classical way.

In css:

```
.textfield2 input{
 ...
}

.textfield1 input{
 ...
}

.textfield1  label,  //<- if the label style of textfield1 and textefield2 are same
.textfield2  label{
 ...
}
```

Be careful, in your HTML you have a space between textfield and the number `<div class="textfield 3">`. That's mean your div has the CSS class *textfield* **and** the CSS class *3*.

If you just want one class remove the space and the code above works.

If you keep the space, just modify `.textfield2` to `.textfield.2` with a dot between *textfield* and the *number* (to indicate that the style it's for the class textfield with the class 2)